# 1971 Mach 1 Mustang

Tags: engine, ford, mustang

I own a 1971 Mach 1 Mustang. Owned it since 1975.
Just got it out of the shop. Ran great. Then started making pop sound/and hesitation. Thought it might be carburetor.

Today, I Cranked it up, it blew white smoke from exhaust, made a loud squeal and shut off. Belts are tight. Help!

Comment: What was the work done at the shop?

Answer (score 0):

Pop the hood and see if the distributor is loose and able to be turned by hand. Not the distributor's rotor, but the entire distributor. The service tech may have made it loose to set timing but failed to re-tighten it before releasing the car to you. If the distributor then slipped in forward rotation, this would make the timing greatly retarded and could explain the popping, white smoke and stalling.